# acess tfs to get capacity information

Tags: c#, tfs, wiql

I am trying to get project information from tfs server programitaically.I want to know how to acess the capacity information.Ive serached for it online and it says that that capacity info is stored in [dbo].[tbl_TeamConfigurationCapacity].
But am not understanding how to query for the table using wiql.Anyone have any idea about it ?

Answer (score 1):

This table is only available in the Project Collection database and querying that table is not supported through SQL nor WIQL. While technically possible through SQL, any direct access of the Project Collection database is unsupported and the underlying structure may change between major versions, updates and even hotfixes.

Instead of directly accessing the capacity in the database, [the supported method is to use the REST api to query the capacity](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/work/capacity).

Example:

```
GET https://{instance}/DefaultCollection/{project}/{team}/_apis/work/TeamSettings/Iterations/{iterationid}/Capacities?api-version={version}

GET https://fabrikam-fiber-inc.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/Fabrikam-Fiber/_apis/work/teamsettings/iterations/2ec76bfe-ba74-4060-970d-4567a3e997ee/capacities?api-version=2.0-preview.1 

{
  "values": [
    {
      "teamMember": {
        "id": "8c8c7d32-6b1b-47f4-b2e9-30b477b5ab3d",
        "displayName": "Chuck Reinhart",
        "uniqueName": "fabrikamfiber3@hotmail.com",
        "url": "https://fabrikam-fiber-inc.vssps.visualstudio.com/_apis/Identities/8c8c7d32-6b1b-47f4-b2e9-30b477b5ab3d",
        "imageUrl": "https://fabrikam-fiber-inc.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_api/_common/identityImage?id=8c8c7d32-6b1b-47f4-b2e9-30b477b5ab3d"
      },
      "activities": [
        {
          "capacityPerDay": 0,
          "name": null
        }
      ],
      "daysOff": [],
      "url": "https://fabrikam-fiber-inc.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/6d823a47-2d51-4f31-acff-74927f88ee1e/748b18b6-4b3c-425a-bcae-ff9b3e703012/_apis/work/teamsettings/iterations/2ec76bfe-ba74-4060-970d-4567a3e997ee/capacities/8c8c7d32-6b1b-47f4-b2e9-30b477b5ab3d"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: i need to acess it through database method explicitly...any idea on how to do it ?

Comment: Your need and the supported solutions don't match. You'll have to use the REST api. Whether you build a job that puts the data into a SQL database so you can query it or whether you call the rest directly is up to you.